# How can I get entered tracking number on Admin Back-End Shipments grid?

Tags: magento-1.9, grid, custom-options, shipment-tracking

I need the tracking number on the Shipments grid in the Back-End,

from here:
[image]

to here:
[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try below code :

Overwrite  class  : **Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Shipment_Grid**

Change Collection Method as Below :

```
 protected function _prepareCollection(){
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
    $shipTable = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/shipment_track');
    $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft($shipTable, $shipTable.'.order_id = main_table.order_id',array('track_number'=> $shipTable.'.track_number'));
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
   }
```

After This Create Column for Tracking Number :

```
$this->addColumn('track_number', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Tracking Number'),
    'index' => 'track_number',
    'filter_index'=>'sales_flat_shipment_track.track_number',
));
```

Work For me 
Happy Coding. :)

Comment: Well come :)   Happy Coding.

Comment: one small error, if tracking number star with numeric its display as  the tracking number, if tracking start with alphabetic its display as 0, how can i solve it.

Comment: https://snag.gy/458x27.jpg

Comment: @AjayPatel :  Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/xyz/public_html/errors/report.php' (include_path='/home/xyz/public_html/app/code/local:/home/xyz/public_html/app/code/community:/home/xyz/public_html/app/code/core:/home/xyz/public_html/lib:.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/xyz/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 925

Comment: when i applied your code i get above error

Comment: i will check and inform you

Comment: https://snag.gy/458x27.jpg    this is the major error, alphabetic and number

Comment: hey just remove type value from column check my updated ans

Comment: @AjayPatel : its getting error, all tracking number display as a same column

Comment: pls replace above your code from previous code, its completely wrong

Comment: just change number to varchar, its working, 'type'  => 'varchar',

Comment: Hey Please check now its work with filter

Comment: I would suggest not to use full table name as it will not work if there is prefix added in database tables. You can use `Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/shipment_track')` to get table name.

Comment: what filter, ..

Comment: @Rathinam You can search tracking number from at top box

Comment: @AjayPatel : yes working good

Comment: ok. Enjoy. :) any more help i am available

Comment: i get confused this line, Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/shi‌​pment_track')     what u try to tell me

Comment: If you have used prefix for your table names, then this code will not work. But you don't then its fine

Comment: @John Please check my updated ans

Comment: did u know about fedex with magento configuration

Comment: yes i know configuration about this

Comment: could you pls help me above that,

Comment: ok but currently i am out side office can you contact me after 9PM

Comment: still i struggle with fedex magento testing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56921/discussion-between-ajay-patel-and-rathinam).

Comment: @AjayPatel : $shipTable = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/shipment_track');
    $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft($shipTable, $shipTable.'.order_id = main_table.order_id',array('track_number'=> $shipTable.'.track_number'));        not working....................

Comment: @AjayPatel : tracking number column display working fine, but the condition not working.....

Comment: @AjayPatel : error page : https://snag.gy/tumAEk.jpg

Answer (score 3):

A better approach to this will be an observer.
Add observer code in your **config.xml** file

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
      <adminhtml_block_html_before>
            <observers>
                <addShipmentNumberToShipmentGrid>
                    <class>Vendor_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>addShipmentNumberToShipmentGrid</method>
                </addShipmentNumberToShipmentGrid>
            </observers>
        </adminhtml_block_html_before>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

Now create **Observer.php** with below code

```
<?php
class Vendor_Module_Model_Observer
{
    public function addShipmentNumberToShipmentGrid(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $this->_grid = $event->getBlock();
        if ($this->_grid instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Shipment_Grid) {
            $this->_collection = $this->_grid->getCollection();
            $this->_collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/shipment_track'), "main_table.order_id = ".Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/shipment_track').".order_id",array('track_number'));

            $columnData = array(
                'header' => 'Tracking Number',
                'index'  => 'track_number',
                'type' => 'text',
            );

            $this->_grid->addColumnAfter('track_number', $columnData, 'shipping_name');
            $this->_grid->sortColumnsByOrder();
            $filter = $this->_grid->getParam($this->_grid->getVarNameFilter(), null);
            if (is_null($filter)) {
                $this->_collection->load();
            }
            $this->_collection->clear();
            if (is_string($filter)) {
                $data = $this->_grid->helper('adminhtml')->prepareFilterString($filter);
                $this->_setFilterValues($data);
            } else {
                if ($filter && is_array($filter)) {
                    $this->_setFilterValues($filter);
                }
            }
            $this->_collection->load();
        }
    }

    protected function _setFilterValues($data)
    {
        foreach ($this->_grid->getColumns() as $columnId => $column) {
            if (isset($data[$columnId]) && (!empty($data[$columnId]) || strlen($data[$columnId]) > 0)
                && $column->getFilter()
            ) {
                $column->getFilter()->setValue($data[$columnId]);
                $this->_addColumnFilterToCollection($column);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    protected function _addColumnFilterToCollection($column)
    {
        if ($this->_collection) {
            $field = ($column->getFilterIndex()) ? $column->getFilterIndex() : $column->getIndex();
            if ($column->getFilterConditionCallback()) {
                call_user_func($column->getFilterConditionCallback(), $this->getCollection(), $column);
            } else {
                $cond = $column->getFilter()->getCondition();
                if ($field && isset($cond)) {
                    $this->_collection->addFieldToFilter($field, $cond);
                }
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

It will also work for filter values.

Comment: @ Jaimin Sutariya : above code good stuff,

Comment: @ Jaimin Sutariya : did you know about Payeezy payment gateway configuration,,

Comment: Thank, but I already told you I am not aware of Payeezy